# Silverstripe's Versioned feature for dataobjects in new release (3.2)

Tags: silverstripe

I want to audit-trail all changes made to dataobjects. Say I have Event dataobject and I want to know who changed it, when changed, what is changed etc. (Similar to Pages). 
Silverstripe site recommends the use of Verioned but I can't find any examples of implementation. It says the best example is Pages which is is already comes with Versioned implemented. The basic rule is to  define an augmentDatabase() method on your decorator. 
So, I want to use DataExtention for dataobject (extension) and then use the extended one for my Event dataobject. But is there any simple example?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to manage and monitor multiple versions of the event DataObject, you simply need to declare that you want to use the versioned extension for thatDataObject

```
Class Event extends DataObject{
    static $extensions = array(
    "Versioned('Stage', 'Live')"
);
    ...
}
```

Then run a dev/build
You should now have a Event, Event_Live, and Event_versions tables.
You can then have a look at the methods available in Versioned.php, and use them with Event, ie publish(). This should get you started.

Comment: So I understand that you can't alter the Event object itself (maybe because it comes from a third party extension). I thought you were writing the Event DataObject. In that case, you could try to decorate Event with Versioned by putting Object::add_extension('Event', 'Versioned("Stage", "Live")'); in mysite/_config.php. This will take care of the versioning aspects through the augmentDatabase() method already implemented. If you need to add more custom logic, you can create your own decorator, and add it by using the same mechanism. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

"Versioning in SilverStripe is handled through the Versioned class. It's a DataExtension, which allow it to be applied to any DataObject subclass."

"Similarly, any subclass you create on top of a versioned base will trigger the creation of additional tables, which are automatically joined as required."

Here is link to read further with examples 
[Versioning of Database Content](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/versioning)